# Disabling and re-enabling the clicked child objects

Tags: unity, c#, 2d

I am currently working on 2D platform game. The following script adding the child objects inside the array and identifies the child object I click on and checks the tag on it. Now I don't know how to disable the child object that I have clicked and I want the disabled child object to be re-enable when I click on another child object inside the same parent object. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class SelectedPlatform : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject platform;
    void Start()
    {
        Transform[] children = new Transform[transform.childCount];
        for (int i=0; i<transform.childCount; i++) 
        {
            children[i]=transform.GetChild(i);
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
         {
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), Vector2.zero);

            if(hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "Platform")
            {
                Debug.Log ("Target Position: " + hit.collider.gameObject.transform.position);
            }   
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be tempted to handle this with two scripts:

```
// Put this on each container object:
public class ToggleableContainer : MonoBehaviour {

    ToggleableItem _currentSelection;

    // On initialization, find all toggleable children of this parent.
    void Start() {
       ToggleableItem[] children = GetComponentsInChildren<ToggleableItem>();
       // Let each child know who to talk to when they're clicked:
       foreach(var child in children)
           child.SetContainer(this);
    }

    // When one platform is clicked, disable it and re-enable the last selection (if any).
    public void Select(ToggleableItem target) {
       if(target == _currentSelection)
          return;

        if(_currentSelection != null)
            _currentSelection.gameObject.SetActive(true);

        if(target != null)
            target.gameObject.SetActive(false);

        _currentSelection = target;
    }    
}
```

.

```
// Put this on each platform object you want to toggle between enabled/disabled:
public class ToggleableItem : MonoBehaviour {

    ToggleableContainer _container;

    // Allow the parent container to register itself.
    public void SetContainer(ToggleableContainer container) { 
        _container = container;
    }

    // For simple click interactions, Unity will handle the raycasting for you
    // if you just implement a method to respond to the "OnMouseDown" message.
    void OnMouseDown() {
        // Tell our container we've been selected - it will handle coordinating the rest.
        if(_container != null)
             _container.Select(this);
    }
}
```